# How to reduce the webpack packaging size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

This is my webpack.dev.config.js

```js
"use strict";
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');
// let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackBrowserPlugin = require('webpack-browser-plugin');

const vendors = ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router'];
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 3001,
        hot: true,
        hotOnly: true,
        inline: true,
        watchContentBase: true,
        watchOptions: {
            poll: true
        },
        contentBase: "./src",
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        clientLogLevel: "none",
        proxy: {
            '/sms-web/*': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9099',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false
            }

        }
    },
    entry: {
        app: "./src/main.js", //
        vendors: vendors //第三方库
    }, //入口文件
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
        publicPath: "",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts"] //resolve.extensions 用于指明程序自动补全识别哪些后缀,
    },
    module: {
        //各种加载器，即让各种文件格式可用require引用
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js|jsx$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: "/node_modules/",
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: "/node_modules/",
            // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader")
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" }
            ]

        }, {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "less-loader" },
            ]
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader",
            query: {
                limit: 10000
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new WebpackBrowserPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require'] //排除关键字
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['vendors'],
            filename: "vendors.bundle.js",
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
    ]
};
```

I use `npm start` to run it in development with `webpack-dev-server`,like this:

```
       "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js"
```

But,when bundle

```
Version: webpack 2.3.3
Time: 17035ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
app.bundle.js    90 kB       0  [emitted]         app
vendors.bundle.js  3.33 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendors
chunk    {0} app.bundle.js (app) 33.5 kB {1} [initial] [rendered]
```

the vendors is 3.33M,  just use react,react-dom.react-router in vendor, i want to know it is normal or should i do something to reduce

Comment: Your config along won't help much, could you share webpack stats dump please? `webpack --profile --json>stats.json`, then upload stats.json. Also you can take a screenshot of your bundle's size-map using https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer tool and share that here.

Comment: I try this way ,it has 251 modules.why so big

Comment: Please make the stats.json available as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to reduce the size of your bundle for a production release, my advice is that you turn off the source-maps: while they're useful during development, they take up a lot of space inside the bundle.

Another useful webpack feature to optimize bundle size is the `-p` flag, that enables extra optimizations.

With just those two practices, I was able to reduce the size of my bundle from ~8 MB to just 1.22 MB for a React application.

Comment: your mean `webpack-dev-server -p`? and how to turn off source-maps

Comment: You don't need to fire up a server to build a bundle. You can simply do something like ```webpack -p``` and the bundle is generated. To disable source maps you can pass ```null``` to your ```devtools:``` option. You can either do this programmatically (maybe using environment variables, required if you want to build your app on Heroku for example) or manually.